# Can't find aws.yml or paperclip.rb files to configure Amazon S3 to use with Paperclip? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, environment-variables, paperclip

I am trying to connect to Amazon S3 services but I can't seem to find the files I need to configure in order to make this happen. I installed these gems in the `Gemfile`:

- `gem 'paperclip'`
- `gem 'aws-sdk'`

And then ran `bundle install`, and restarted the server.

When I run `rails g paperclip pictures image`, the command works and create the migration file like it's supposed to, so Paperclip does *appear* to be working correctly in that sense. `rake db:migrate` creates the columns as expected as well.

According to these two tutorials [Uploading Files to S3 in Ruby with Paperclip](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) and [rubydoc.info](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3), I should have these two files available to me:

- `aws.yml`
- `paperclip.rb`

But they are no where to be found. I have searched the entire directory up and down already and I've looked this up multiple times on Google and SO and it seems that no one else is having this problem.

Am I forgetting to do something or is there an alternative way to configure Paperclip with S3 in my Rails app?

Note: I am **not** using Heroku, so I would prefer to learn about a way that does not implement Heroku.